# PCL surface reconstruction code in C++ using surface poisson algorithm takes too long to execute and generate ply files for larger 3d point cloud data

Tags: c++, pcl

I am trying to perform surface reconstruction using PCL library in C++.The code works fine but it takes too long to perform surface reconstruction and generate ply file for larger input txt files(>5MB).The code is given below.

```
#include <pcl/point_types.h>
#include <pcl/io/pcd_io.h>
#include <pcl/io/ply_io.h>
#include <pcl/features/normal_3d.h>
#include <pcl/surface/poisson.h>
#include <fstream>
#include <chrono> // Added for time measurement
#include <filesystem> // Added for directory creation

using namespace std;
using namespace pcl;
namespace fs = std::filesystem;

string inputfile = "input/idol.txt";
string outputfile = "output_mesh.ply";

int main(int argc, char** argv)
{
    // Start the timer
    auto start = std::chrono::steady_clock::now();

    // Create the output directory if it doesn't exist
    fs::path outputDir("output");
    if (!fs::exists(outputDir))
    {
        fs::create_directory(outputDir);
    }

    // Open the input text file
    cout << "Reading " << inputfile << " File" << endl;
    ifstream input_file(inputfile);

    // Parse the text file line by line to extract the point coordinates
    PointCloud<PointXYZ>::Ptr cloud(new PointCloud<PointXYZ>);
    string line;
    int points = 0;
    float x, y, z;
    while (getline(input_file, line))
    {
        istringstream iss(line);

        if (!(iss >> x >> y >> z))
            return -1;

        cloud->push_back(PointXYZ(x, y, z));
        points++;
    }
    cout << "Loaded " << points << " points" << endl;

    // Estimate normals for the point cloud
    search::KdTree<PointXYZ>::Ptr tree(new search::KdTree<PointXYZ>);
    cout << "Normalizing" << endl;
    PointCloud<Normal>::Ptr cloud_normals(new PointCloud<Normal>);
    NormalEstimation<PointXYZ, Normal> ne;
    ne.setInputCloud(cloud);
    ne.setSearchMethod(tree);
    ne.setRadiusSearch(0.5);
    ne.compute(*cloud_normals);

    // Concatenate the XYZ and normal fields
    cout << "Concatenating" << endl;
    PointCloud<PointNormal>::Ptr cloud_with_normals(new PointCloud<PointNormal>);
    concatenateFields(*cloud, *cloud_normals, *cloud_with_normals);

    // Create a Poisson object and set its parameters
    cout << "Setting Poisson parameters" << endl;
    Poisson<PointNormal> poisson;
    poisson.setDepth(10);
    poisson.setSamplesPerNode(4);
    poisson.setPointWeight(2);
    poisson.setIsoDivide(10);
    poisson.setInputCloud(cloud_with_normals);

    // Perform surface reconstruction
    cout << "Performing surface reconstruction" << endl;
    PolygonMesh triangles;
    poisson.reconstruct(triangles);

    // Save the result to file
    string outputPath = (outputDir / fs::path(outputfile)).string();
    cout << "Saving result to " << outputPath << endl;
    io::savePLYFile(outputPath, triangles);

    // Stop the timer
    auto end = std::chrono::steady_clock::now();

    // Calculate the elapsed time for the complete process
    auto duration = std::chrono::duration_cast<std::chrono::milliseconds>(end - start);
    cout << "Finished" << endl;
    cout << "Total elapsed time: " << duration.count() / 1000.0 << " seconds" << endl;

    return 0;
}
```

When i run the above code it generates a smooth mesh of the point cloud data...But i want to increase the execution speed of the code..I want to generate ply file within 10-20 seconds

Comment: How big are your point clouds. I always achieve the most optimization by reducing the amount of points (e.g. with VoxelGrid).